# initializing task struct members in init_task

Tags: linux, init

Ive added a new field to my task struct in /include/linux/sched.h

It is an Integer.

How do i initialize the value of it to be 0 in the task struct of init
when it runs for the first time?

EDIT:
it is for a custom linux kernel with custom system calls.
Also this is a rather technical question, on how and where to initialize fileds i customly added to task_struct
also, where should i add the task_struct field to?

Comment: Do you mean `/usr/include/sched.h`? Why are you editing files in system directories? Don't do that. They will get overwritten on the next system update. Any code you write based on these changes will only work on your system and fail to compile on everybody else's. That said, please [edit] your question and show the `struct`. Do you have a [mcve] on how you want to use it?

Comment: to be honest, the kernel doesnt even boot, i think it might have something to do with a uninitialized variable